# How cat suspends while reading a port?

Tags: cat, serial-port

When we `cat` a regulat text file's content, everything is printed out and the command terminates. However, when we `cat /dev/ttyS0`, the command hangs and waits new data to come.

What is the reason of this suspension?

Comment: it does not suspend but wait for more input since when it does not get *eof*

Comment: @cuonglm Ok then, if you write this as answer, I'll accept. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Experimenting with `cat` in a terminal

`cat` is waiting for more data, as [cuonglm says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404653/how-cat-suspends-while-reading-a-port#comment723696_404653). The same thing happens when you type in `cat` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> so that its input is your terminal. In the terminal you can experiment easily with the behavior of `cat`. So first, to begin, here's a description of how to do that.

When you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in your terminal, the terminal doesn't send a literal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> character to a program. For that, you would need to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to tell the terminal that the next control character should be treated literally, followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Instead:

- If there is text in the input buffer--that is, you have entered text that has not yet been sent to the program--then the buffer is flushed, which is to say that it is sent to the program. The program will receive it on its next read.
- If there is no text in the input buffer, then the terminal indicates end-of-input to the program, which will cause it to encounter the end-of-file condition on its next read operation, which (see below) is actually the *current* read operation, in this situation, because `cat` is already reading.

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, in addition to indicating a [newline character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), *also* causes the buffer to be flushed, even though you have not pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Therefore you will observe:

- Entering text and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> causes `cat` to write the same text to your terminal. With <kbd>Enter</kbd>,  `cat` writes the newline character, too.
- Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the beginning of a line, or doing so after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, sends a newline character and `cat`  writes one.
- Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> at the beginning of a line or after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (i.e., doing so twice in a row) ends the input.

  When `cat` sees that there is nothing more to read from its last source of input (remember, "cat" stands for "catenate" or "concatenate," which is how it behaves when it receives multiple filename arguments), it quits.

Just as `cat` waits for input when it is reading from its controlling terminal until the input is finished, so too does it wait for more input form any other file or  device, including serial terminals, if that's what you tell it to read from.

Note that the special behaviors associated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which cause your input to be sent to `cat`, are behaviors of *your terminal*, and not  of `cat`. In particular, `cat` does not itself treat newlines specially.

### The state of a waiting process

When `cat` is waiting for your input, try inspecting its state from another terminal.

On most Unix-like operating systems, you can find the process IDs of all running cat processes by running `pidof cat` or `pgrep -x cat`. At least *one* of those is usually supported. Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in the same terminal where `cat` is running to suspend it--this *actually* suspends the process--then run `ps` to find its PID, then resume it by running `fg`. Or run `tty` in the first terminal to show the pathname of the terminal device--in GNU/Linux this may look like `/dev/tty2` or `/dev/pts/4`--then run `cat`, and then in the second terminal run `ps -t tty`, replacing *`tty`* with the output of `tty` in the first terminal.

In a second terminal, run `ps pid` where you replace *`pid`* with the actual process ID of the cat process. This will list the process, including a column showing its state. (Even if you already ran `tty -t` above, this will be necessary on some systems, including GNU/Linux, which will not have included the state column before.)

For example, I did this on a GNU/Linux system:

```
ek@Io:~$ ps 30196
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
30196 pts/4    S+     0:00 cat
```

Yours may look different. I recommend running `man ps` and looking up the process state codes that appear under the STAT or S column, which differ somewhat across systems. On that GNU/Linux system, [ps(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ps.1.html) reveals that the process's state has been reported as:

```
               S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
```

```
               +    is in the foreground process group
```

On that GNU/Linux system, if I run `cat` and then suspend it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> as described above, the `S+` changes to `T`:

```
               T    stopped by job control signal
```

There's interruptible sleep, so is there *uninterruptible* sleep? Yes:

```
               D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
```

This typically occurs when a process is in the middle of an IO operation that the kernel does not allow to be cancelled. A process in uninterruptible sleep cannot be killed. If you use `kill pid` or even `kill -9 pid`, it receives the TERM or KILL signal (respectively) once the operation is complete.

### Tracing the process

Normally to debug a program you would open it in a debugger like `gdb` or `lldb`. However, some systems including GNU/Linux have a utility called `strace` that you can use to see what *system calls* a process is making. When you use `strace` to run a process that waits on input from a terminal, you can see each of the `read` calls that block its execution until more input is sent to the process on the terminal. If you have a GNU/Linux system such as Fedora, CentOS, Debian, or Ubuntu (those are examples--there are many others), try running this command:

```
strace cat
```

You'll see a whole bunch of system calls: first those that execute the process (`execve`, followed by various calls involving filenames with `ld.so` in them if the program uses shared libraries, which it almost certainly does), then those that run for most programs to make it so C library functions can work, including `mmap` and `brk`... and then eventually it will read from [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29):

```
read(0,
```

That's the syntax of `strace`. The `cat` process is *not* literally in the middle of passing arguments to `read` (as that syntax might look like to a C programmer who has not used `strace` before). Instead, it has made the `read` system call, *which has not returned yet*. It will return when data are read, or when end of input is reached.

Try typing something, like `foo`, and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then you will see something like:

```
"foo\n", 131072)                = 4
write(1, "foo\n", 4foo
)                    = 4
read(0,
```

What does that mean? If you quit `cat` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> at the beginning of a line, or just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> anywhere) and re-run it while suppressing its output by redirecting it to `/dev/null`, you'll be able to see more easily:

```
strace cat >/dev/null
```

You still see output from `strace` because it is written to [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) and you only redirected [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29). But now `cat`'s own output--`foo` and a newline, just as you gave it--is not shown. What you see after typing `foo` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> looks like:

```
"foo\n", 131072)                = 4
write(1, "foo\n", 4)                    = 4
read(0,
```

This is to say that the `read` calls finishes, reading `foo` followed by a newline, which is shown to you as `\n`. `cat` then calls `write` to write that same string to its output. Probably `cat` does not have a `write` call in its C code. Instead it probably uses a C library function like `fprintf`  or `fputs` to perform the write, which is not shown in the output of `strace` because it is not a system call, and which works ultimately by using the `write` system call. The `4` is passed to `write` to tell it--that is, to tell the kernel--that four bytes should be written: `f` `o` `o` `\n`.

Notice that, after calling `write`, `cat` calls `read` again to continue reading input. You can continue giving it input and seeing it call `write` and then `read` again. For example, I typed `abracadabra` and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
"abracadabra\n", 131072)        = 12
write(1, "abracadabra\n", 12)           = 12
read(0,
```

When you're done, having pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) after the last thing you typed, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. That ends the input, `cat` quits, and `strace` shows you something like this:

```
read(0, "", 131072)                     = 0
munmap(0x7f856a591000, 139264)          = 0
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```